# How to use parsedown in Laravel 5.4

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, composer-php

In Laravel 5.4 have included Composer package `"erusev/parsedown": "~1.6"`
 https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.4/composer.json#L22

But how I can use this class in controller?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved this Question to use parsedown in controller laravel 5.4, we only initial parsedown class without use namespace like this:

```
 $parsedown = new \Parsedown();
 $md = $parsedown->text('# this H1 tag');
```